# Extract tar to a directory, removing any files it contains NOT present in the archive

Tags: tar

Say I have a large tar, the contents of which I am regularly extracting to a constant location.

I am wanting to keep this location a pristine instance of the extracted tar, and I could avoid the very wasteful process of always wiping out the output directory just to update it with a small change the tar might have by using the `--keep-newer-files` flag.

But what would I do about removing files from the output location that no longer exist in the archive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard `tar` command has a way to list the contents of an archive.  The short form for this is `tar -tf archive.tar`.

By using this together with `find`, `grep`, and command substitution, you get the following:

```
rm -f $(find . -d | head -n -1 | grep -Fv "$(tar -tf archive.tar)")
```

Run this *in* the directory where you want the contents of the archive, and replace `archive.tar` with the path to the archive file.

Working from right to left for the pipeline inside the outermost command substitution:

- `find . -d`: Lists all the files and directories under the current directory, listing them in depth-first order.  The depth-first ordering is important here, as we plan to use this file list for deletions and therefore must delete directory contents before deleting directories themselves.
- `head -n -1`: Exclude the last line from the `find` command.  This will remove the entry for `/path` itself, which may or may not be present in the archive.  If we weren't doing things in depth-first order, this would instead be `tail -n -1`.
- `grep -Fv "$(tar -tf archive.tar)"`: Pass the listing of the archive to a grep command, which will then filter out those lines from the list returned by `find`, so only the files which aren't' in the archive will be passed to the outter `rm` command.

A couple of notes:

- This probably isn't *quite* POSIX compliant. It should work in GNU bash though.
- This is dependent on how tar reports the archive contents and how the archive was created.  In particular, the listing has to match up with how `find` reports things.  With GNU tar and most archives, it *should* work.  If it doesn't for your case, you can probably get it to work by using either `sed` or `awk` on the output of the tar command inside the innermost command substitution.
- Make sure and test this before using it on production data, if it doesn't work for either of the two above reasons, it's liable to remove *everything* form the directory you run it in.

Comment: Great answer. Some slight tweaks:
1. `Find` omits trailing slashes from directories, preventing matching those output from `tar -t`.
2. `tar -t` can potentially skip the printing of some directories.
E.g. If a tar file contains only `foo/dir1` and `foo/dir2`, `tar -t` will print those paths but not necessarily `foo/`. I can't explain this behaviour entirely either.
I'm tolerating these directories not being removed for now - they will always be empty anyway. Thus I now have:
`rm $(find . -depth -type d -printf '%p/\n' -o -print | head -n -1 | grep -Fv "$(tar -tf ../*.tar)" | grep -v /$)`

Comment: Why were my edits rejected @Goro?

Comment: @Goro and Romeo Ninov, small corrections to syntax errors to _not_ fall under the "This edit was intended to address the author of the post" rejection reason.

Comment: @BrettRogers why do you think the `find` arguments are inverted? `-d` (= `-depth`) is a global option, so it can come before or after the `.`.

Comment: @muru `-d` is indeed a global option, but is still considered part of the `[expression]` section, the entirety of which must be after the path argument. Trying to use `-d` before the path produces an error in GNU find.

Comment: @BrettRogers I see. One place where a GNU tool is less flexible in argument parsing than the BSD version.

Answer (score 3):

You could rely on the fact that extracted file will have a `ctime` later than the time you started extracting the archive.

So:

```
touch start
tar xf archive.tgz
find . -depth ! -cnewer start -print0 |
  sponge /dev/stdout |
  xargs -r0 echo rm -d
```

(here assuming GNU tools or compatible and `sponge` from `moreutils`, used to delay the removing until the full list has been gathered as otherwise deleting a file would update the ctime of its parent directory).

Remove the `echo` to actually do it (after you've verified it did what you wanted).

Answer (score 0):

The `grep -v` trick did not work for me, as the archive was kinda big and the command bailed with [Argument list too long](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=Argument+list+too+long). So here's an approach I used to remove the accumulated cruft of a MediaWiki installation:

```
$ tar -tzf mediawiki-1.35.0.tar.gz | cut -d/ -f2- > foo
$ find /var/www/mediawiki/ | cut -d/ -f5- | while read f;
     do grep -qw "^${f}$" foo || echo "not in archive: ${f}"; done
```

One will have to play around with the `-f` argument to `cut` a bit to get it right, and the command here does not *remove* anything, it will just print out what's *not* included in our archive.